# Replay a logfile at "realtime" speed?

Tags: logging, real-time, hbase, simulation, flume

I'm starting to work on a tool that should be able to process logfiles from a system (like apache, syslog, etc) in near realtime.

I'm gearing towards tools like storm/flume/hbase-coprocessors to implement this.

Because I want to be able to test this offline at "full production speed" I'm looking for a tool that can help me replay old production logfiles at the same rate as when I would have hooked the system to our production environment.

I've been thinking and essentially this is what I have in mind:

1. Per logfile I run the tool with some parameters:

   - Which logfile
   - What part of the line is the timestamp
   - Time offset with 'now'
2. This tool then reads the file (no output) until it sees 'now+offset'.
3. Then it starts outputting the lines at roughly the same speed as the timestamps in the logfile indicate.

Is there an existing tool that does something like this?

Or is there a better solution to run such an offline "full speed" simulation?

Answer (score 4):

I think the following open source library (written in GO) might do what you are asking for:
https://github.com/buger/gor/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It seems this libary replays the traffic against a webserver (instead of feeding it into a stream processing thing like storm). Yet it seems to be a good starting point for me. Thanks.